# Javascript - Passing static value to a callback function

Tags: javascript

I want to create callback function with some parameters, but I want that one of the values within never change and be set when the function is created!

P.e.

```
let a = 2;
let y = (b) => { let staticValue = a; return staticValue * b; }

y(1) => 2 -> OK
```

then

```
a = 3
y(1) => 3 -> Not OK -> I want the function to have the original value of a.
```

I know, this happens because the variable a is only evaluated when the function is called. But is there any workaround?

Comment: Why don't you just use b * 2 or similar if you really want to make it static ?

Comment: Possible with `localStorage` and all that mess - but why bother? Just hard code the value into the function

Comment: Yes, I need to "remember" the original value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this with what is called an [IIFE (immediately invoked function expression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)

```js
let a = 2;
const y = (staticValue => b => staticValue * b)(a);

a = 44;
console.log(y(1));
```

What's happening here is that you have two functions. The first one, `staticValue => ...` is immediately invoked, and `staticValue` is given the value of `a`. Since `a` is given as an argument of the IIFE, once the function is invoked `staticValue` won't change, even if the value of `a` is changed.

The return value of the first function is a second function, `b=> ...`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let a = 2
let makeY = () => {
  let staticValue = a;
  return (b)=> staticValue * b;
}
let y = makeY();
```

or

```
let a = 2
let y = ((staticValue, b) => {
  return staticValue * b;
}).bind(null, a)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```js
function first (a) {
    function second (b) {
          return a * b;    
    }
    return second;
}

let x = first(2)  // the inner function second will close around the variable a which is 2 in this case

console.log(x(3))

let y = first(5)  // the inner function second will close around the variable a which is 5 in this case

console.log(y(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could apply a Functional programming approach.

```js
const getYFn = (a , b) => {
  return a * b;
}

const a = 2

const y = getYFn.bind(null, a);

// the constant y now is a function that partially applied first param
console.log(y(1)); // 2
console.log(y(3)); // 6
```